# AJAX post failing XMLHttpRequest check in Django view

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have a simple html page which renders with a number of nearly identical forms for the user to submit.  Upon submit, the view is intended to add a row to the database, recreate the list of forms with slightly updated data, and send it back to the browser ('/route/complete/' maps to add_completed_route_view in urls.py).

This works perfectly the first time.  Once the page has been redrawn with the new list of forms, however, the next submit will fail the request.is_ajax() test I have in the view.  That causes it to skip to request.REQUEST['next'] and subsequently to home_view.

I've commented it out below, but I've also tried appending c['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest' to the view but it hasn't helped.

I'm looking for help in ensuring that the headers continue to have the appropriate XMLHttpRequest param while the user submits through AJAX.  Code is below, and help is much appreciated.

```
script.js

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".doneForm").submit(function() {
    var route_id = $(this).find('input[name=route_id]').val()
    var next = $(this).find('input[name=next]').val()
    var reqData = {route_id:route_id,next:next}


    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/route/complete/",
      data: reqData,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#routeTable").html(data);
      }
    });
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

and

```
template.html

<div id="routeTable">
  {% for route in route_list %}
  <div id="routeDone">
    <form class="doneForm" action="/route/complete/" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="route_id" value="{{ route.route_id }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
      <input type="submit" value="Done" class="doneButton" />
    </form>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and

```
views.py

def add_completed_route_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated():
        add_completed_route(request)
        if request.is_ajax():
            wall_slug = get_wall_slug_from_route_id(request.REQUEST['route_id'])
            c = get_context_for_wall_page(request, wall_slug)
            # c['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
            return render_to_response('m/js_route_table.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.REQUEST['next'])
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_view'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once the Ajax is completed, it replaces the original form with a new one - and this one no longer has the javascript event handler attached, so the next time the form submits via the normal POST method.

Luckily, jQuery has a couple of methods that handle this for you - `live` and `delegate`. So instead of `$(".doneForm").submit(function() ...`, do this:

```
$(".doneForm").live("submit", function() {...
```

Comment: Daniel, you are a sparkling font of life-saving javascript wisdom.  Problem solved and I just learned something new about how JS works - thanks!